# Stubbing slack alert usinng sinon not working

Tags: javascript, sinon

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
const  URL = process.env.slackUrl;
const slack = require('slack-notify')(URL);

describe('stub slack alert',()=>{
it('',()=>{
sinon.stub(slack, 'alert')
})
})
```

I want to stub slack.alert method using this code but slack.alert method not stubbing it still alerting in slack

Answer (score 0):

```
describe('stub slack alert', () => {
  it('', () => {
    // create a stub for the slack.alert method
    const stub = sinon.stub(slack, 'alert');

    // call the method that uses slack.alert
    // replace this with your actual code that uses slack.alert
    slack.alert('test message');

    // assert that the stubbed method was called once with the expected argument
    sinon.assert.calledOnceWithExactly(stub, 'test message');

    // restore the original implementation of slack.alert
    stub.restore();
  });
});
```

Create a stub for the "slack.alert" method using "sinon.stub", call the method that uses "slack.alert" with a test message, and then use "sinon.assert.calledOnceWithExactly" to assert that the stubbed method was called once with the expected argument.
Finally, restore the original implementation of "slack.alert" using the "stub.restore()" method.